# Ticket Dispenser : Array in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, caching, memory

I have a ticket dispenser.

It is non efficient. 3300 ms response.

It was previously implemented with a ticker (counter.increment!) which brought problems dealing with concurrency.

It is currently implemented as array.shift.

```
ticket_roll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ticket = ticket_roll.shift
```

Any user can grab a ticket.
The first one to hit the array gets the ticket.

**controller**

```
def create

    @movie = Movie.find_by(movie: params[:movie])
    ticket_roll = TicketRoll.find(1).ticket_roll
    @ticket = ticket_roll.shift


    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email        => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card         => params[:stripeToken],
    )
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer     => customer.id,
        :amount       => 1500,
    )

    if charge["paid"]
      @movie.update_attributes(status: "sold", email: params[:stripeEmail],
                                    first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name])
      Pusher['the_channel'].trigger('the_event', {message: ticket_roll[0]})

    else
      ticket_roll.unshift(@ticket)
    end

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end
```

Can I store the ticket_roll array in memory/cache so that each user does not = a full DB query ?

Comment: I still find it hard to imagine. What does `TicketRoll.find(1).ticket_roll` do? I know TicketRoll.find(1) always fetches the record with the id as 1, but what does the method `ticket_roll` do?

Comment: @Finks It's not a method, ticket_roll is the attribute which contains the actual ticket array. There is only 1 ticket_roll.

Comment: Where is that 3300ms going? Are you sure it is db related ?(as opposed to stripe api calls for example)

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned having all the tickets in the memory is inefficient and simply using `increment!` poses concurrency issues. One basic solution to that is to use [locks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update) when updating a record.

An example from the guide:

```
Item.transaction do
  i = Item.lock.first
  i.name = 'Jones'
  i.save
end
```

In your case you only need to have the number of latest ticket in DB. Before giving out a new ticket number you should lock the record, increment the value and release the lock.

Comment: Would this end up queuing the requests? If so, assuming the transaction ends up taking 1 second and you have 100 ticket buyers, wouldn't some of them be waiting over a minute?

Comment: It should consume time in milliseconds. But any ways, you need somehow to lock your object either on DB level or in memory. If you do it on memory level and your server dies for any reason, you will also loose the track of given tickets.